# How to write geolocation data as an array into Google Firebase Realtime Database with Angular HttpClient?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to **build** an `Ionic geolocation tracking app` on `Android` with the `Cordova Geolocation plugin`. The tracking implementation works fine so far. Now I am tying to write the coords with  `Angular HttpClient` into the `Firebase Realtime DB`. But somehow it doesn't work.

The connection to the `Firebase RDB` works fine, if I just write one coord e.g. `resp.coords.latitude`. However, if I try to write the full **array** with `lat and lng`, it doesn't work anymore.

The coords will be shown in the `console.log` but not in our `Firebase RDB`.

I suppose it might be an issue with the `watchLocation() function`.

**Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?**

**tracking.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { GeolocationService } from '../../app/geolocation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tracking',
  templateUrl: './tracking.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tracking.page.scss'],
})
export class TrackingPage implements OnInit {
  geoLatitude: number;
  geoLongitude: number;
  geoAccuracy: number;
  timestamp: any;

  watchLocationUpdates: any;
  isWatching: boolean;

  constructor(
    private geolocation: Geolocation,
    public geolocationService: GeolocationService,
  ) { }

  getMoment() {
    return moment().milliseconds(0);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log('navigator.geolocation works well');
    }
  }

      // Start location update watch
      watchLocation() {
        const options = {
          maximumAge: 3600000,
          timeout: 3000,
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
       };
        this.isWatching = true;
        this.watchLocationUpdates = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options);
        this.watchLocationUpdates.subscribe((resp) => {
          this.geoLatitude = resp.coords.latitude;
          this.geoLongitude = resp.coords.longitude;
          this.geoAccuracy = resp.coords.accuracy;
          console.log('watchLocation function called', resp);
          this.geolocationService.insertUserGeolocation(resp)
            .subscribe(() => {
              localStorage.setItem('lastLocation', JSON.stringify(resp));
              console.log(`user location data inserted in FB`, resp);
            });
         });
    }

      // Stop location update watch
      stopLocationWatch() {
        this.isWatching = false;
        console.log('this.isWatching = ', this.isWatching);
        this.watchLocationUpdates.unsubscribe();
      }
}
```

**geolocation.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment  } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GeolocationService {
  databaseUrl = environment.firebase.databaseURL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello OrganizationService Provider');
    console.log('OrganizationService: ', this.databaseUrl);
  }

  insertUserGeolocation(data) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.databaseUrl}/geolocations.json`, data);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that writes to Firebase in your question. Am I overlooking something? If you're new to interacting with Firebase, I recommend starting here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `post`, you should firebase's api. First initialize thr db:

```
  // Set the configuration for your app
  // TODO: Replace with your project's config object
  var config = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();
```

Then you can add data to the database:

```
function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but the connection is set and works perfectly fine. I suppose it has something to do with the watchLocation() function.

Answer (score 1):

Better use [GeoFire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geofire). This requires a specific structure of the nodes, but it permits queries by GPS fix.

Also see [Location Queries With Firebase GeoFire and Angular Google Maps (AGM)](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/geofire-location-queries-with-google-maps/).